# Why is my image not aligning in the center?

Tags: html, css, css-float, stylesheet

I am not able to figure out why my image in between the label is not aligning to the center , even though I have declared the css inline , but the priority is not working.

I have declared text-align as left in the `<style>` tag , but I want only this particular tag to align center and not others.

here is my html ,

```
<td class="ospy_td" style="background-color:#ddd;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;style=text-align:center">
    <label class="ospy_lab" style="text-align:center">
        <img id="bt" src="img/bt.png" width="30" height="29" />
    </label>
</td>
```

Here is my CSS, which is deined within a  tag in the same html page,

```
.ospy_td, label {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: default;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#0066c0;
};
```

Comment: Would you mind cleaning up your code (remove quotes from string concatenation, etc) or at least copy + paste the page source here?

Comment: yep done that , sorry

Comment: Did you miss that or it's really like this in the source? `<\/label>`

Comment: You can't nest a style in a style: style=text-align:center is in your style attribute.

Comment: Your `<img/>` needs `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` in order for `text-align` to have any impact.

Comment: Also, you have one style within the other, which is wrong: `style="background-color:#ddd;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;style=text-align:center"`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sZ3LD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of errors here in CSS and usage of html elements.

But one them that creates the issue, is the `style=` inside style attribute:

<td class="ospy_td" style="background-color:#ddd;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
**style=**
text-align:center"
>

Delete this "style=" and thing will work.

---

My suggestion code change ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rN2B4/)):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="ospy_td">
            <i class="ospy_lab" />
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    background: #66f;
    text-align: center;
}
.ospy_td {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    cursor: default;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
i.ospy_lab {
    background-image: (img/bt.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #0066c0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 29px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.ospy_td, label {
    text-align: left; // this is your problem, change to center
}
```

you forgot a semicolon here

```
 style="text-align:center"
```

change to

```
style="text-align:center;"
```

Comment: The OP wants every other one left aligned and that particular one, centred. That's why the inline style is being used, to overwrite this rule.